# elimination of conscutive regions (generalization: ones with zeros between) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I need effectively eliminate (by zeroing) the consecutive "1's" between "-1's" at each column of matrix A, which now can be separated by any zeroes. The number of consecutive "1's" between "-1's" is > N. This is a non-trivial generalization of my previous [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52537450/elimination-of-consecutive-regions).

Again, typical size(A) = [100000,1000].

See example:

```
  A =
       1    -1     0
       0     1     1
       0     1     1
       1     1     0
       0     0     1
       1    -1     0
      -1     1     1
      -1     0    -1
       1     1     1
       0     1    -1
```

For N = 2 the expected result is

```
Aclean =
       0    -1     0
       0     0     0
       0     0     0
       0     0     0
       0     0     0
       0    -1     0
      -1     0     0
      -1     0    -1
       1     0     1
       0     0    -1
```

For N = 3 the expected result is

```
Aclean =
      1    -1     0
      0     1     0
      0     1     0
      1     1     0
      0     0     0
      1    -1     0
     -1     1     0
     -1     0    -1
      1     1     1
      0     1    -1
```

Comment: In your example for `N = 2`, you have removed the first 3 `1` values in the first column, but those values are **not** between `-1` values and the number of consecutive `1` values is not greater than 2. I don't think I understand your conditions.

Comment: I need to eliminate (zeroed) all "1's" which are located between "-1's" and start/end at each column of A separately. The number of eliminated "1's" between "-1's" is greater than user defined N.
So in my example, in 1st column of A are three "1's" and any number of "0's", separated by two "-1's" and then one "1's". For N = 2 I will eliminate only first 3 > (N=2) "1's". For N = 3 I do not eliminate any "1's" from 1st columns of A. Similarly for all columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, if I understand the question, is a way using `cumsum` and `accumarray`:

```
N = 3;
sep = A==-1;
sep(1,:) = true;
idx = cumsum(sep(:));
sep(1,:) = A(1,:)==-1;
num = accumarray(idx, A(:)==1);
iff = num <= N;
Aclean  = reshape(sep(:)|iff(idx), size(A)) .* A;
```

Comment: Results does not fit to my examples...  Number of "1's" between "-1's" and start/end which is > N of each column of matrix A is zeroed.

Comment: I am still looking for any speed up improvement …

Big test matrix: A = double(rand(100000,1000)>.4) - double(rand(100000,1000)>.7); N = 10;

Comment: You can split `A` horizontally,so you  can split it to for example  4 parts each of size `[100000 x 250]` and process each part separately and concatenate the results. Try different partitioning and see which one is more efficient.

Comment: Could be possible to create mask term mask = reshape(sep(:)|iff(idx), size(A))  with zeros only on positions where are actually "1's" at A??? I am using mask term for additional processing. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Do you mean `a(:)~=1` ?